# [[:: not found in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I get the following errors with my bash script.

```
ncompile.sh: 1: ncompile.sh: ###: not found
ncompile.sh: 52: ncompile.sh: [[: not found
Chose your Operating System. {Supported OS: Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, FreeBSD}
Debian
ncompile.sh: 61: ncompile.sh: [[: not found
ncompile.sh: 61: ncompile.sh: [[: not found
ncompile.sh: 70: ncompile.sh: [[: not found
ncompile.sh: 70: ncompile.sh: [[: not found
ncompile.sh: 79: ncompile.sh: [[: not found
Pick a valid OS
```

With this script:

```
###
### Functions to simplify stuff :)
###

debianDeps() {
    apt-get install git cmake build-essential liblua5.2-dev \
        libgmp3-dev libmysqlclient-dev libboost-system-dev
}

fedoraDeps() {
    yum install git cmake gcc-c++ boost-devel \
        gmp-devel community-mysql-devel lua-devel
}

bsdDeps() {
    cd /usr/ports/shells/bash && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/devel/git && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/devel/cmake && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/lang/gcc47 && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/lang/luajit && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/devel/boost-libs && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/math/gmp && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/databases/mysql-connector-c && make install clean BATCH=yes
}

libInstall() {
    echo "Libraries and Build Tools... Installed"
}

bsdBuild() {
    echo "Building on FreeBSD"
    mkdir build && cd build
    CXX=g++47 cmake ..
    make
}   

genBuild() {
    echo "Building..."
    mkdir build && cd build
    cmake ..
    make
}

clean() {
    mv *.cpp *.h src/ && mv *.o objs/
    echo "There might be a few leftover files."
}

###
### Script starts here
###
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "You must be root to use this script, press enter to exit."
    read end
    exit 1
fi

echo "Chose your Operating System. {Supported OS: Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, FreeBSD} "
read ans1 

if [[ $ans1 = "Fedora" ]] || [[ $nas1 = "CentOS" ]]; then
    echo -n "Should the script install dependencies? y/n"
    if [[ $ans1_1 = "y" ]]; then
        fedoraDeps
    elif [[ $ans1_1 = "n" ]]; then
        break
    else
        echo "Answer '\y\' or \'n\' "
    fi
elif [[ $ans1 = "Debian" ]] || [[ $ans1 = "Ubuntu" ]]; then
    echo -n "Should the script install dependencies? y/n"
    if [[ $ans1_1 = "y" ]]; then
        debianDeps
    elif [[ $ans1_1 = "n" ]]; then
                            break
                        else
                            echo "Answer '\y\' or \'n\' "
                        fi
elif [[ $ans1 = "FreeBSD" ]]; then
    echo -n "Should the script install dependencies? y/n"
        if [[ $ans1_1 = "y" ]]; then
            bsdDeps
        elif [[ $ans1_1 = "n" ]]; then
            break
        else
            echo "Answer '\y\' or \'n\' "
        fi

        else
            echo "Pick a valid OS"

        fi
```

Comment: Are you sure your script is launched with bash ? Basic shell doesn't have `[[` only `[`.

Comment: Script is missing a shebang line.

Comment: @Zulu I was running "sh myscript.sh" now I did "bash myscript.sh" and it worked.

Comment: @Paul R when I use the shebang I get an error related to a missing directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should begin by insert bash she-bang at first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I think your script basically uses `sh`. shell only support simple bracket (`[`).

Comment: When I add that I get this: ./ncompile.sh: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory

Comment: @user3084450, you add the shebang line, and then make your script executable with `chmod a+x ./ncompile.sh`. You can the execute it without having to specify "sh" or "bash" : `./nocompile.sh`

Comment: @Zulu I think you wanted to write *shell __only__ supports simple bracket (`[`)*

Answer (score 0):

the variable ans1_1 does not read, you must "read ans1_1" before using it